# Sparse matrix is very slow in loop, how to speed it up in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a huge matrix(584064x5369468) and I have to use sparse matrix in Matlab, but in my calculation it is very slow to assign a value to a sparse matrix. I cannot wait to finish it, what should I do.

```
cgm=sparse(584064,5369468);
[Xcp, Ycp, Zcp] = ndgrid(-[1:336],-[1:45],-[1:336]);
% dp my data which is loaded

for sg=1:335 
    for tg=1:44
        for rg=1:335
            % ii is a vector i.e the size of ii = 309x1
            fprintf('Constructing patch: %i %i %i',sg,tg,rg)
            ii=find(abs((Xcp(sg,tg,rg))<=abs(dp(:,1)))&abs((dp(:,1))<abs(Xcp(sg+1,tg,rg)))&(abs(Ycp(sg,tg,rg))<=abs(dp(:,2)))& (abs(dp(:,2))<abs(Ycp(sg,tg+1,rg)))& (abs(Zcp(sg,tg,rg))<=abs(dp(:,3)))&(abs(dp(:,3))<abs(Zcp(sg,tg,rg+1))));

              % jj is another vector i.e the size of jj = 64*1
              %the ii size is changing every time but the size of jj is always 64. ii is non-zero values and can be between 1 and 584064 .
              % c is my matrix after calculation i.e c = 309x64
             cgm(ii,jj)=c;
        end
     end
end
```

For the first internal loop it goes very fast but it become slower and slower drastically.

I know that assigning value to sparse matrix means repack everything and it is very slow, but how to repack it less in my code?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. You're not using the loop variables and I have no idea how that assignment is working with `ii` and `jj` being different sizes.

Comment: @beaker i use loop variables to make ii and jj values. should I update my code?

Comment: I think that would help.

Comment: @breaker I edited the code for `ii ` ,but for `jj` calculation is very long but it calculates some index for `cgm` matrix. my code is working with small matrix but with huge matrix i have to use sparse matrix and it is very slow

Comment: @beaker the `ii` is changing everytime  but the size of `jj` is always 64. `ii` is non-zero values and the size of it can be between  1 and 584064 .

Comment: Minor comment.  You have a lot of unnecessary `abs` calls.  For example. doing `abs(Xcp(...));` is superfluous because `Xcp` always has positive numbers.  I encourage you to edit that line to remove all of the unnecessary `abs` calls so that it's easier to read.  I may be inclined to help after that point.

Comment: @rayryeng I edited the above code, in my code it is negative actually.

Comment: I'm still very confused about your calculations, but you should be accumulating the rows, columns and values for each non-zero and using `S = sparse(i, j, v)` as shown [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) (or maybe `S = sparse(i, j, v, m, n)`).

Comment: @Ehsan - Those negatives added to `ndgrid` were not there before. Either way, thanks.

Comment: @beaker , i should use this in the loop? Is it possible to add i and j and v as a vector?

Comment: @Ehsan - `i`, `j`, and `v` are all `N x 1` vectors and populate your sparse matrix `C` such that `C(i(k), j(k)) = v(k)` for `k = 1, 2, ... , N`. All other values would be zero.  I would also recommend you override the size and do `C = sparse(i, j, v, 584064,5369468);` so that you're sure you get the desired size.

Comment: @rayryeng i edited after you mentioned

Comment: I try and let you know the result, thanks for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @beaker mentioned above, and as I explain in my *Accelerating Matlab Performance* book, using the `sparse` or `spdiags` functions is much faster than using indexed assignments as in your code.

The reason is that any such assignment results in a rebuilding of the sparse data's internal representation, which is increasingly slower the more data elements need to be rearranged.

Instead, you should accumulate the data indices (`ii` and `jj`) as well as the assigned data (`c`) into three separate arrays within your loops, and then, ***outside*** the loop use a single call to `sparse(ii,jj,c)` to update the matrix in a single go. This will be much faster.

See pages 137-140 in my book for additional details and suggestions related to sparse data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, im doing the same thing now. Waiting for result. Thanks again